# How to create dynamic system menu in Mac Catalyst Swift app

Tags: swift

I have created a class for a menu when I put the buildMenu function in this class I get two error Method does not override any method from its superclass and Cannot find type 'UIMenuBuilder' in scope. Everything works as expected If I put this in the AppDelegate file

[image]

I tried to add the AppDelegate as a subclass to the MidiMenu class

```
class MidiMenu: AppDelegate {
    
    
    override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
        super.buildMenu(with: builder)
        
        builder.remove(menu: .file)
    }
}
```

I am hoping to have a dynamic menu that will create a new menu item in the following way

1.) I have profile system menu option
2. when I press create new profile I get alert box
3. I enter the name of the new profile and press okay it will create a new child menu item Under the system profile menu option

I am new to swift so my approach was to put the buildMenu in different class but this must be the wrong way

```
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
       super.buildMenu(with: builder)

       /// Remove items
       builder.remove(menu: .file)
       builder.remove(menu: .edit)
       builder.remove(menu: .format)
        
       let menuAction = UIAction(title: "Create New Profile", image: nil, handler: { [] (_) in
           
           // Alert with textfield action
           })
       
       let menu = UIMenu(title: "Profiles", children: [menuAction])
       builder.insertSibling(menu, afterMenu: .application)
       
      
     }
```

Comment: "Everything works as expected If I put this in the AppDelegate file" So why not just do that instead? That is what you are supposed to do after all. Creating another class, inheriting your app delegate, and then overriding `buildMenu` makes no sense. And I suspect you didn't import UIKit.

Comment: I'm assuming you are on Mac Catalyst? Because none of these APIs is available on macOS proper.

Comment: My hopes was to have dynamic menu. For example I have a Alert that have textfield. When I hit the okay button I would like the menu to update with new option. That's why I put it in different class. Am I do this wrong. Should this method only go in the AppDelegate. Yes Mac Catalyst. Are they any other options to build a menu

Comment: That sounds like a context menu?  You should override it in your view controller instead. Please [edit] your question to explain exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Just updated the question I hope its more clear of what I am hoping and the current issue I have